# Search For An Elemnent In A Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do i find  a certain element in a tuple and print out the index of the element.

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
b = int(input('enter the element you want to find'))
if b in a :
    print('found')
```

here is the simple program. now how do print the index of the element whic needs to be searched

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.index`:

```py
if b in a:
    print(a.index(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate as well:

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
b = int(input('enter the element you want to find'))
for x,y in enumerate(a):
    if b == y:
        print(x)
```

**Edit:**

to find the multiple indices of an element:

Suppose we have b at 3 positions, now if you want to find all the three indices then:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,2,8,2)
b = 2

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x == b:
        print(i)
1
6
8
```

with list comprehension :

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == b]
#[1, 6, 8]
```

Comment: hi, thanks!....btw can u say how to do for  nested lists/tuple ?

Comment: yes, you can! you can find the index for multiple instances as well

Comment: how to do it...i tried but not sure bout it

Comment: one moment I will give you the code.

Comment: @ganeshmurthy please see now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251551/discussion-between-ganesh-murthy-and-god-is-one).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print(a.index(b))
```

[Use this link for working with tuples](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-find-an-element-in-tuple-by-value/)

Comment: this answer is already present !

Comment: I posted it before but I have a slow internet. I didn't see the other answer
Should I remove my answer ?